# UIDatePicker with N/A option

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Currently in my app I need to display N/A in `DatePicker` if I am getting an empty value from the backend. Is there an option to display N/A in `UIDatePicker`?

Answer (score 1):

If your recieve empty data from server add one object in

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Method.

Comment: He is asking about `UIDatePicker` not about `UIPicker`

Comment: Yes, i understood. My intention is, If s/he receive data from server with empty just show N/A on UIPIckerView in reference of UIDatePicker View.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of displaying "N/A" with `UIDatePicker`.

`UIDatePicker` is not a subclass of `UIPickerView`.

You can

1. Disable the `UIDatePicker`
2. Substitute the `UIDatePicker` for a `UIPickerView` with a single "N/A" row when there is no data.
3. Substitute the `UIDatePicker` for a button "No date set: Click to add a date" and pop up a `UIAlertController` with an embedded `UIDatePicker`. Add the options of "Set date" or "Cancel" to revert to the unset state.
4. Implement your own date picker (Find a starting point on [Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com))